# Windows 8 application Resolution

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have developed Windows 8 application. and when I try to run it , to test it on another laptop ;  the design got worst and everything appear in bad way.(Fonts, images, ..)
Is that related to the resolution ? If yes How I can solve it ?

Comment: do you have the resolution of each device? portrait,landscape, etc

Comment: The video DPI setting matters here, dots per inch.  Designing on a high DPI machine and displaying on a low DPI machine tends to lead to disappointment.

Answer (score 1):

How was your app developed? Is this a xaml/cs app or html/js app for windows 8 store apps? Is it in the store yet or only testing? Are multiple resolutions supported?

You'll want to test out various resolutions to see how your app handles them. Two links to test out here with your application:

[Windows Store app Development Snack: Simulator tips & tricks](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/windows-store-app-development-snack-simulator-tips-tricks)

[Scaling to different screensre](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Another area to check is pixel density. Follow the [guidelines for scaling to pixel density](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465362.aspx) to ensure your app looks great when scaled.